# Changing instance attributes of a parent class from a child class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to make it so that when a Boxer object is created there is no need to specify the breed as it is automatically set to Boxer

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        # instance attributes
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
class Boxer(Dog):

    super().__init__().breed = "Boxer"

    def speak(self,sound = 'woof'):
        print(f'{self.name} says {noise}')

hettie = Boxer('Hettie',5)
hettie.speak()
```

At the moment when I run this code I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

I tried initially to put the `super()` line inside the `__init__()` method but then I had an issue with not enough arguments when I called Boxer

```
def __init__(self):
    super().breed = "boxer"
```

but if I added arguments I still had issues

```
def __init__(self,breed):
    super().breed = "boxer"
```

Comment: It's unclear what your attempted `__init__` implementation was, but I would expect something like `def __init__(self, name, age): super().__init__(name, age, "Boxer")`. Calling the no-args super in the class body certainly won't work.

Comment: Also `__init__` always returns None, you will get an error if you try to set the `.breed` atribute at `super().__init__().breed = "Boxer"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your call to `super()`'s method inside the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, name, age): # Also provide all the parameters
    super(Boxer, self).__init__(name, age, breed="Boxer")
```

Notice that you can optionally provide the classname `Boxer` and the instance `self` to `super` as arguments (if you don't it will be done automatically) and you also need to provide all the arguments passed in the `__init__` method into the `super().__init__` method. Because the constructor `__init__` always returns `None` you cannot modify any of it's attributes like you did. You just have to set `self.breed = "Boxer"` or just pass in `"Boxer"` as the parameter to the cosntructor.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked `def __init__(self, name, age):  super(Boxer, self).__init__(name, age, breed="boxer")`. Is there any documentation I can read on this as the python docs for classes don't really explain any of this

Comment: @Henry Garrett [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods).